# Eclipse p2 alternative for custom install handlers

Tags: eclipse, installation, p2, pde

Before p2, one could write a custom install handler with a feature that was executed to do any 'custom' task during installation.

I see that with p2 the custom install handler is no longer supported.
I keep hearing about 'custom touchpoints' being the replacement for that.

However I cant find any concrete example/documentation for it.

Can anyone tell me how to get the functionality of custom install handlers with the p2 update manager.

**Edit:** A description of what I want to do -

I need to edit the eclipse.ini file and set the -Xmx property to a value based on whether we are running inside a 64 bit or 32 bit env.

**Edit 2:** I tried creating a p2.inf file in my feature with the following line -

```
instructions.install = \
addJvmArg(jvmArg:-Xmx900m);

instructions.install.import= \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.addJvmArg,
```

and it works, however it does not differentiate between 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: You don't need to use custom touchpoints for that. I'm pretty sure that you can specify JVM args in the product definition.

Comment: how do you check whether one is running 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: Hm. Maybe that is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**p2.inf** definitely is the right place to perform customized actions. It is a good place to add vm arguments into .ini. You could put a **p2.inf** under your feature/plug-in.

**Updated on 20 Dec.**:

I tried it on my own environment, it works well to set different vm args when installing the same feature on linux 32bit and 64bit. You could download the [example code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064358/p2.inf.zip) to play with it.

```
#create a requirement on the IU fragment we are creating
requires.2.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
requires.2.name=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86
requires.2.range=[1.0.0,1.0.0]
requires.2.greedy=true
requires.2.filter=(&(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.arch=x86))

#create a IU frament named configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86 for linux 32 bit
units.0.id=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86
units.0.version=1.0.0
units.0.filter=(&(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.arch=x86))
units.0.provides.1.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
units.0.provides.1.name=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86
units.0.provides.1.version=1.0.0
units.0.instructions.configure=addJvmArg(jvmArg:-Xmx500m);
units.0.instructions.configure.import=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.addJvmArg,

#create a requirement on the IU fragment we are creating
requires.3.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
requires.3.name=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86_64
requires.3.range=[1.0.0,1.0.0]
requires.3.greedy=true
requires.3.filter=(&(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.arch=x86_64))

#create a IU frament named configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86_64 for linux 64 bit
units.1.id=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86_64
units.1.version=1.0.0
units.1.filter=(&(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.arch=x86_64))
units.1.provides.1.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
units.1.provides.1.name=configure.com.example.yourfeature.linux.x86_64
units.1.provides.1.version=1.0.0
units.1.instructions.configure=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.addJvmArg(jvmArg:-Xmx900m);
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work :(

i even removed the units.o.filter line. 
Also if I am correct for the line :
units.0.hostRequirements.1.name=com.example.yourfeature 
the feature name had to replaced with the actual id of my feature.

Comment: is there any way to debug this?

Comment: how do you deploy your features? using PDE export or PDE build? You can remote debug both of those way, add breakpoint into org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse.AdviceFileAdvice class

Comment: update the example code. You would try to deploy a repository of a sample rcp to have a look at the content.xml for reference.

Comment: Kane, the updated code also doesnt seem to work. btw, going down this train of thought though, how would this be modified to check for a 32 bit version too so that a lower value for xmx can be set for 32 bit and higher for 64 bit?

Comment: As for deploying, right now i am just creating a local update site from within eclipse and installing it using the eclipse installer gui which uses the p2 director i guess

Comment: @pdeva, I tried it by myself, and made a small example to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most complete docs on the matter is the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Touchpoint_Instructions). You're probably interested in "native touchpoint actions", but it is also possible to implement your own touchpoint action, i.e. a Java class which is invoked as part of the installation process.

EDIT: [Customizing Metadata](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata) contains some info on what you can put in the p2.inf file. The example given there is:

```
 instructions.install = \
    ln(targetDir:@artifact,linkTarget:foo/lib.1.so,linkName:lib.so);\
    chmod(targetDir:@artifact,targetFile:lib/lib.so,permissions:755);
 instructions.install.import= \
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.ln,\
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.chmod
```

Comment: I think I need the custom touchpoint action, ie invoke my own Java class. However I dont see any info for it in the wiki page.

Comment: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/05/23/custom-touchpoints-in-p2/  here is the link for custom touchpoint tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There are two articles that explain how to achieve this:

- [How to Add Custom Install Actions to Your Next Eclipse IDE Plug-in](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-add-custom-install-actions-to-your-next-eclipse-ide-plug-in/)
- [Custom touchpoints in P2](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/05/23/custom-touchpoints-in-p2/)

First one covers a bit more options, second is only about P2 touchpoints.

**WARNING:** when we added custom touchpoints to our plugin, it started deadlocking (quite often, but not always) at install time (we did not want the risk and removed them). Maybe we did something wrong but this is something to be aware of.

[Built-in touchpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html) seem to work fine, though.