# add parameters to eclipse.ini file

Tags: eclipse, plugins, parameters, initialization

I´m creating a plugin here and to execute it correctly, we need to set the original parameter -Xmx512m to -Xmx1536m (1,5GB).

Is there any way of doing this programmatically, when I´m installing the plugin?
Or any other way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [This blog](http://pweclipse.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/p2-can-update-your-eclipseini.html) talks about using the p2 installer for this

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.
But do you have anything about how to add p2 to my plugin development?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a p2 touchpoint to add/modify JVM arguments to the host Eclipse installation. It's not terribly difficult but neither is it trivial. Start with [this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html) (too detailed to summarize here). [This other SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431967/eclipse-p2-alternative-for-custom-install-handlers) also has an example, but with less explanation.

Basically, you'll need to include an appropriately configured `p2.inf` file in your installable feature.

Comment: Thanks.
Should I add the p2.inf file to my project or to my Feature Project?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it belongs in the Feature project, since that's usually the Installable Unit; but check the documentation to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, but I´m quite new to plugin development and to p2, as well.
Do you have any good material so I can start with it?
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: There are 2 links in my answer.